# How to avoid logo on beamer been covered by graphics

Tags: beamer

While using Beamer I found that when I add figures, if they are big enough they will cover the logo on the bottom-right. How can I define the logo to be on top of every image? The solution I am using so far is to decrease the size of the image so it will not reach the logo. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting.
A suggestion: Change your username to something more telling than "user23640".

Comment: Hi that could be quite hard. As far as i understand the code left and right sidebars are typeset and shiped out before the frame content.  Would it be a option to add the logo to the foot? That could be done by a rather easy template modification. But for that we would need a bit more of information.

Answer (score 2):

The logo is quite deliberately typeset 'early', before the content of the slide proper. The working assumption is that the logo is less important than the slide payload (which is unique to the current slide, unlike the logo). It may be possible to hack around this, but that would require details of the detail of your use of `beamer`.